# Flutter share PDF with name

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, share-plus

I am using the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) - package for sharing a PDF. It is working, but I want to pass the original name of the PDF-file. Currently my PDFs always get a random name (e.g. "9caef563-bdbe-4cb2-85d2-e582870bbdd3.pdf"), even though I am passing the `name`:

```
final response = await Dio().get(
    event.url,
    options: Options(
      headers: headers,
      responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
    ),
  );
  final result = await Share.shareXFiles(
    [
      XFile.fromData(
        response.data,
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',
        name: event.filename,
      ),
    ],
  );
```

What am I missing here? Why is it not passing the correct name?

Comment: This seems to be an open issue on github. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1548

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be an open issue on github.](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1548)

The current workaround is setting a file path for the file you're creating.You could try passing the 'path' property to XFile.fromData or, creating a new file and then passing it to your share.